# How can I load certain files based only on environment with Terraform?

Tags: terraform, terraform-template-file

To run my terraform scripts, I do `terraform apply -var 'ENV=dev' -var-file="dev.tfvars"`

Within `dev.tfvars`, I want to load other files that have variables ONLY for the dev environment.

I should be able to do the same with `staging.tfvars`, etc.

Any thoughts?

Comment: why not have just have the values for your variables in the relevant `tfvars` file.  You mention in your question that you have `dev.tfvars` and `staging.tfvars` is there a reason you can't just have the values in the files?

Comment: You can't load additional files from a `.tfvars` file. How are you executing `terraform`? You would typically inject the filename in during this process so similar to `terraform apply -var 'ENV=$ENV' -var-file="$ENV.tfvars"`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I see it, you have 2 options:

- Using TF workspaces, that allows you to set up small differencies among environments. As stated in the [docs](https://www.terraform.io/docs/state/workspaces.html), you will need to change your resources to use the interpolation sequence `terraform.workspace`. I find this harder to maintain.
- Create a TF wrapper

The wrapper would receive the environment and the TF command, will link environment dependant `.tf` files and call `terraform`loading the `.tfvars` file. For example, you can have an `env/` directory with this files:

```
env/
 | dev.tf
 | staging.tf
 | prod.tf
```

And your wrapper will link, in the project root directory, the proper file, like this:

`env.tf -> env/dev.tf`

Then it will call `terraform $2 -var-file="$1.tfvars" -var 'ENV=$1'`

This way, terraform will read the `env.tf` file contents a load it with your additional `.tf` files.

Comment: I have created a wrapper bash script with a one-liner:
`terraform $1 -var-file="env_global_vars.tfvars" -var-file="cmp_global_vars.tfvars" -var-file="env/$2.tfvars" -var-file="cmp/$3.tfvars"`

Thank you for the eye-opening suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of this approach I'd instead rework the structure of your Terraform codebase so the dev/staging/prod environments etc are all in separate directories and differ only by the `terraform.tfvars` file in each directory.

The best way to do this in my opinion is to liberally use both modules and symlinks. I discussed this in [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43209092/2291321) to a related question about multi tenancy with Terraform.

An example layout may look something like this:

```
$ tree -a
.
├── dev
│   ├── eu-west-1
│   │   ├── bar
│   │   │   ├── bar.tf -> ../../../stacks/bar.tf
│   │   │   ├── eu-west-1.tf -> ../../../providers/aws/eu-west-1.tf
│   │   │   └── terraform.tfvars
│   │   └── foo
│   │       ├── eu-west-1.tf -> ../../../providers/aws/eu-west-1.tf
│   │       ├── foo.tf -> ../../../stacks/foo.tf
│   │       └── terraform.tfvars
│   ├── global
│   │   └── baz
│   │       ├── baz.tf -> ../../../stacks/baz.tf
│   │       └── us-east-1.tf -> ../../../providers/aws/us-east-1.tf
│   └── us-east-1
│       ├── bar
│       │   ├── bar.tf -> ../../../stacks/bar.tf
│       │   ├── terraform.tfvars
│       │   └── us-east-1.tf -> ../../../providers/aws/us-east-1.tf
│       └── foo
│           ├── foo.tf -> ../../../stacks/foo.tf
│           ├── terraform.tfvars
│           └── us-east-1.tf -> ../../../providers/aws/us-east-1.tf
├── modules
│   ├── bar
│   │   └── main.tf
│   └── foo
│       ├── main.tf
│       ├── outputs.tf
│       └── vars.tf
├── production
│   ├── eu-west-1
│   │   ├── bar
│   │   │   ├── bar.tf -> ../../../stacks/bar.tf
│   │   │   ├── eu-west-1.tf -> ../../../providers/aws/eu-west-1.tf
│   │   │   └── terraform.tfvars
│   │   └── foo
│   │       ├── eu-west-1.tf -> ../../../providers/aws/eu-west-1.tf
│   │       ├── foo.tf -> ../../../stacks/foo.tf
│   │       └── terraform.tfvars
│   ├── global
│   │   └── baz
│   │       ├── baz.tf -> ../../../stacks/baz.tf
│   │       └── us-east-1.tf -> ../../../providers/aws/us-east-1.tf
│   └── us-east-1
│       ├── bar
│       │   ├── bar.tf -> ../../../stacks/bar.tf
│       │   ├── terraform.tfvars
│       │   └── us-east-1.tf -> ../../../providers/aws/us-east-1.tf
│       └── foo
│           ├── foo.tf -> ../../../stacks/foo.tf
│           ├── terraform.tfvars
│           └── us-east-1.tf -> ../../../providers/aws/us-east-1.tf
├── providers
│   └── aws
│       ├── eu-west-1.tf
│       └── us-east-1.tf
├── stacks
│   ├── bar.tf
│   ├── baz.tf
│   └── foo.tf
└── staging
    ├── eu-west-1
    │   ├── bar
    │   │   ├── bar.tf -> ../../../stacks/bar.tf
    │   │   ├── eu-west-1.tf -> ../../../providers/aws/eu-west-1.tf
    │   │   └── terraform.tfvars
    │   └── foo
    │       ├── eu-west-1.tf -> ../../../providers/aws/eu-west-1.tf
    │       ├── foo.tf -> ../../../stacks/foo.tf
    │       └── terraform.tfvars
    ├── global
    │   └── baz
    │       ├── baz.tf -> ../../../stacks/baz.tf
    │       └── us-east-1.tf -> ../../../providers/aws/us-east-1.tf
    └── us-east-1
        ├── bar
        │   ├── bar.tf -> ../../../stacks/bar.tf
        │   ├── terraform.tfvars
        │   └── us-east-1.tf -> ../../../providers/aws/us-east-1.tf
        └── foo
            ├── foo.tf -> ../../../stacks/foo.tf
            ├── terraform.tfvars
            └── us-east-1.tf -> ../../../providers/aws/us-east-1.tf
```

This enables you to define the exact configuration of your Terraform code in a single place (the `stacks` directory) with only allowed overrides through each directory's `terraform.tfvars` file. In the above layout we have a `foo` and a `bar` module we want to apply in 2 different AWS regions in all of dev/staging/production and also some non configurable Terraform code that should be applied globally for each of the environment levels (think something like IAM roles etc).

We define our modules under the modules folder (with `foo` potentially being a complete module while `bar` may be a sourced module from a third party location such as another Git repo or [Terraform's module registry](https://registry.terraform.io/)). We then provide a thin wrapper for the modules in the `stacks` folder that may look something like this:

```
variable "name" {}

variable "count" {
  default = 2
}

module "foo" {
  source = "../../../foo"
  name   = "${var.name}"
  count  = "${var.count}"
}
```

Then in each `${environment}/${region}/foo/terraform.tfvars` we always define a name (because it is required) and optionally define a count (which is defaulted):

```
name  = dev-foo
count = 1
```

or

```
name = production-foo
```

The above layout also makes it very obvious to see all of your environments and configuration at a glance and can simplify any wrapper scripts you use with Terraform for setting up state configuration by just using the directory path.