# How to use a common file across many Terraform builds?

Tags: structure, terraform, hcl

I have a directory structure as follows to build the Terraform resources for my project:

```
s3
  main.tf
  variables.tf
  tag_variables.tf

ec2
  main.tf
  variables.tf
  tag_variables.tf

vpc
  main.tf
  variables.tf
  tag_variables.tf
```

When I want to build or change something in s3, I run the Terraform the s3 directory.
When I want to build the ec2 resources, I cd into that folder and do a Terraform build there.
I run them one at a time.

At the moment I have a list of tags defined as variables, inside each directory.
This is the same file, copied many times to each directory.

Is there a way to avoid copying the same tags file into all of the folders? I'm looking for a solution where I only have only one copy of the tags file. 
Terraform do offer a solution of sorts using the "local" verb, but this still needs the file to be repeated in each directory.

What I tried:

1. I tried putting the variables in a module, but variables are internal to a module, modules are not designed to share code into the main file.
2. I tried making the variables an output from the module but it didn't like that either.

Does anyone have a way to achieve one central tags file that gets used everywhere? I'm thinking of something like an include of a source code chunk from elsewhere? Or any other solution would be great.

Comment: Symlinks work great for this. There's a few related questions about structuring Terraform code bases on the site that you might find useful and could answer your question. If you find one in particular that solves your problem you might want to consider voting to close your own question as a duplicate of that one.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43209092/2291321

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for that advice ydaetskcoR, I used symlinks and this works perfectly.

I placed the tags list.tf file in a common directory. Each Terraform project now has a symbolic link to the file. (Plus I've linked some other common files in this way, like provider.tf).

For the benefit of others, in Linux a symbolic link is a small file that is a link to another file, but it can be used exactly like the original file.

This allows many different and separate Terraform projects to refer to the common file.

Note: If you are looking to modularise common Terraform functions, have a look at [Terraform modules](https://www.terraform.io/docs/modules/index.html), these are designed to modularise your code. They can't be used for the simple use case above, however.